# Como passar um float sem perda de valor para um inteiro?

Tags: java, conversão-de-tipo, float

Tenho uma variável float que pode conter qualquer número nela, preciso testar se ela cabe um um número inteiro sem perder valores. Pensei em usar algum teste para ver se os números após a vírgula são 0's ou não. Alguém sabe como?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apenas com um `if` consegue testar se o valor que a variável tem é inteiro ou não, verificando se o valor coincide com o valor truncado da mesma, utilizando o `Math.floor`:

```
float f = 1.0f;

if (f == Math.floor(f)){ //que irá dar verdadeiro
```

[Exemplo para testar](http://ideone.com/R5kU0o)

Answer (score 0):

Bom, quando você for converter um float, double ou outro tipo que tenha decimais para inteiro, sempre terá a perda da parte decimal.

Também vale notar que float e double não são precisos, se quiser precisão veja o BigDecimal.

Se está ciente de tudo isso, basta você comparar os valores com as constantes Integer.MAX_VALUE e Integer.MIN_VALUE:

```
float f = 123.456f;
if(f <= Integer.MAX_VALUE && f >= Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
    // parte inteira de f está dentro da faixa do int
}
```

Abaixo um teste que demonstra alguns problemas envolvendo ponto flutuante e sua saída:

```
public class TestesSO {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float floats[] = { 1.0f, 2.1f, 3.3333f, 4.4f, 5.999999999f, 6.0f, (float) Integer.MAX_VALUE, (float) Integer.MAX_VALUE + 0.1f,
                (float) Integer.MIN_VALUE, (float) Integer.MIN_VALUE - 0.1f };
        double doubles[] = { 1.0, 2.1, 3.3333, 4.4, 5.999999999999, 6.0, (double) Integer.MAX_VALUE, (double) Integer.MAX_VALUE + 0.1,
                (double) Integer.MIN_VALUE, (double) Integer.MIN_VALUE - 0.1 };

        System.out.println("** floats **");
        for (int i = 0; i < floats.length; i++) {
            float f = floats[i];
            int n = (int) f;
            System.out.printf("%15d == %15.15f ? %b (%s em um int)%n", n, f, (float) n == f,
                    (f <= Integer.MAX_VALUE && f >= Integer.MIN_VALUE) ? "cabe" : "não cabe");
        }
        System.out.println("** doubles **");
        for (int i = 0; i < doubles.length; i++) {
            double d = doubles[i];
            int n = (int) d;
            System.out.printf("%15d == %15.15f ? %b (%s em um int)%n", n, d, (double) n == d,
                    (d <= Integer.MAX_VALUE && d >= Integer.MIN_VALUE) ? "cabe" : "não cabe");
        }

    }
}
```

Segue a saída do programa:

```
** floats **
              1 == 1,000000000000000 ? true (cabe em um int)
              2 == 2,099999904632568 ? false (cabe em um int)
              3 == 3,333300113677979 ? false (cabe em um int)
              4 == 4,400000095367432 ? false (cabe em um int)
              6 == 6,000000000000000 ? true (cabe em um int)
              6 == 6,000000000000000 ? true (cabe em um int)
     2147483647 == 2147483648,000000000000000 ? true (cabe em um int)
     2147483647 == 2147483648,000000000000000 ? true (cabe em um int)
    -2147483648 == -2147483648,000000000000000 ? true (cabe em um int)
    -2147483648 == -2147483648,000000000000000 ? true (cabe em um int)
** doubles **
              1 == 1,000000000000000 ? true (cabe em um int)
              2 == 2,100000000000000 ? false (cabe em um int)
              3 == 3,333300000000000 ? false (cabe em um int)
              4 == 4,400000000000000 ? false (cabe em um int)
              5 == 5,999999999999000 ? false (cabe em um int)
              6 == 6,000000000000000 ? true (cabe em um int)
     2147483647 == 2147483647,000000000000000 ? true (cabe em um int)
     2147483647 == 2147483647,100000000000000 ? false (não cabe em um int)
    -2147483648 == -2147483648,000000000000000 ? true (cabe em um int)
    -2147483648 == -2147483648,100000000000000 ? false (não cabe em um int)
```